# Paypal Instant Payment Notification with PHPMailer

Tags: paypal-ipn, phpmailer

I used php() mail function before with IPN and it worked great.

```
$iemail = $_POST['payer_email'];

$to      = $iemail;
$subject = 'somethinghere';
$message = '

Thank you for your purchase

$headers = 'From: support@mydomain.org' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: support@mydomain.org' . "\r\n" ;

//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This worked great but I'd like to attach couple of files to my email.

So $iemail is a table in mysql database.

So these is how I tried with PHPMailer:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$iemail = $_POST['payer_email'];

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = $iemail;
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("something.pdf");      // attachment
```

The problem is I don't get any email with this script. I'm doing something wrong I'm sure but I don't know what. Could you guys please help me?

Thank you.

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php
       //Change these with your information
    $paypalmode = 'sandbox'; //Sandbox for testing or empty ''
    $dbusername     = 'ipn'; //db username
    $dbpassword     = 'password'; //db password
    $dbhost     = 'mysqlhost'; //db host
    $dbname     = 'ibn_table'; //db name


if($_POST)
{
        if($paypalmode=='sandbox')
        {
            $paypalmode     =   '.sandbox';
        }
        $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www'.$paypalmode.'.sandbox.paypal.com'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $payerid = $_POST['payer_id'];
            $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
            $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
            $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
            $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
            $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
            if (!$conn)
            {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

            // insert in our IPN record table
            $query = "INSERT INTO ibn_table
            (itransaction_id,ipayerid,iname,iemail,itransaction_date, ipaymentstatus,ieverything_else)
            VALUES
            ('$transaction_id','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate', '$paymentstatus','$otherstuff')";

            if(!mysql_query($query))
            {
                //mysql error..!
            }
            mysql_close($conn);

        }
}



// PHPmailer ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$iemail = $_POST['payer_email'];

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($iemail);
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('cont.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->Body = 'Hello this is a test message';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/portfolio/service.jpg');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, get the [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Even the example in the README is much better than the ancient code you have there. Look in the examples folder for more complex ones, including extracting data from MySQL to put into your messages.

Comment: Thank you. I found that example.
I've website where is a buy it now paypal button.
After someone clicks to the buy it now button and the express checkout completed paypal sends all information I can receive    through my ipn.php and then those information goes to mysql db.
Then PHPMailer should be able to pull those information and then it should be able to send the email out. My problem is I don't know how to configure it. Mysql works good.

Comment: You need to break up your problem into smaller pieces and solve them separately. PHPMailer has nothing to do with MySQL, but you can get data from MySQL, process it into an appropriate message body and give it to PHPMailer. You can find plenty of documentation on all these things.

Comment: You're totally right but I don't have experience with  these things. I updated my first post. MYSQL is working fine. I can send out emails automatically after payments if I'm using php() mail. Just I couldn't attach files. So I found that I should use PHPMailer if I want to use attachments.

I copied PHPMailerAutoload.php into my root directory. I believe that's the only thing I need.

Comment: You need the whole Phpmailer package (all the files must be kept together), but you only need to include the auto loader into your script.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the whole package. Does my code look ok?

Comment: That looks much better. You're not actually setting the Body, so your messages may turn up blank. You should be using mysqli rather than the obsolete mysql functions.

Comment: I'm still not getting any email. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I edited my first post again.

Comment: It's working. I've to figure it out how to add more attachments.

Comment: If I add an extra $mail->addAttachment('images/portfolio/service.jpg'); it won't send the mail. How can I attach more than 1 file?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What happens instead? What does your mail server log say?